# Bad request when running ASP.NET 2.0 application

Tags: asp.net, bad-request

I am developing website in ASP.NET 2.0. I am running a page. In button click event I deal with data readers (first it gives me different error). So I debug it, and when I debug my 2 datareaders, then it gives me the error `HTTP 400 bad request`. I don't know how to recover. I check path but it is correct.

Comment: We would need more info to help.  Code samples would be good.  Where in your code is the error occurring would be good, too.

Comment: Could you please share your code with us ? Thanks.

Comment: Please give us the code that produce the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a permission problem to this file. But I can't really some thing accurate unless you give us more information about your problem.